# How to include a list of objects in Oracle's XMLTABLE?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltable

I have the following (minimal) XML:

```
<root>
  <person>
    <name>Miguel Martins</name>
    <age>32</age>
    <list_of_numbers>
      <number>1</number>
      <number>2</number>
    </list_of_numbers>
  </person>

  <person>
    <name>Another Person</name>
    <age>19</age>
    <list_of_numbers>
      <number>3</number>
      <number>4</number>
    </list_of_numbers>
  </person>
</root>
```

And the following query:

```
with my_with_clause as
 (select '
<root>
  <person>
    <name>Miguel Martins</name>
    <age>32</age>
    <list_of_numbers>
      <number>1</number>
      <number>2</number>
    </list_of_numbers>
  </person>

  <person>
    <name>Another Person</name>
    <age>19</age>
    <list_of_numbers>
      <number>3</number>
      <number>4</number>
    </list_of_numbers>
  </person>
</root>
' my_xml
    from dual)
select t1.*
  from my_with_clause,
       xmltable('/root/person' passing xmltype(my_with_clause.my_xml) columns name path 'name', age path 'age') t1;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
+----------------+-----+
|      Name      | Age |
+----------------+-----+
| Miguel Martins |  32 |
| Another Person |  19 |
+----------------+-----+
```

So far, so good. Now, I'd like to add the numbers to the table whose alias is T1. That is, I desire the following output:

```
+----------------+-----+-------------+
|      Name      | Age | Some_Number |
+----------------+-----+-------------+
| Miguel Martins |  32 |           1 |
| Miguel Martins |  32 |           2 |
| Another Person |  19 |           3 |
| Another Person |  19 |           4 |
+----------------+-----+-------------+
```

I have tried adding the some_number column to the XMLTABLE. That is:

```
with my_with_clause as
 (select '
<root>
  <person>
    <name>Miguel Martins</name>
    <age>32</age>
    <list_of_numbers>
      <number>1</number>
      <number>2</number>
    </list_of_numbers>
  </person>

  <person>
    <name>Another Person</name>
    <age>19</age>
    <list_of_numbers>
      <number>3</number>
      <number>4</number>
    </list_of_numbers>
  </person>
</root>
' my_xml
    from dual)
select t1.*
  from my_with_clause,
       xmltable('/root/person' passing xmltype(my_with_clause.my_xml) columns name path 'name', age path 'age', some_number path 'list_of_numbers/number') t1;
```

However, I do not get the desired output. Instead, I get the following error:

> ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node

How can I achieve the desired output? Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f759/2) for you to try out (if necessary).

Comment: Do you always get single XML as literal or do you need an approach that supports multiple rows with XML?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I don't think I quite understand your question... I'd say it's the latter, but again, I'm not 100% sure on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chained XMLTable calls:

```
select t1.name, t1.age, t2.some_number
from my_with_clause
cross join xmltable (
  '/root/person'
  passing xmltype(my_with_clause.my_xml)
  columns name varchar2(20) path 'name',
    age number path 'age',
    list_of_numbers xmltype path 'list_of_numbers/number'
) t1
cross join xmltable (
  '/number'
  passing t1.list_of_numbers
  columns some_number number path '.'
) t2;

NAME                        AGE SOME_NUMBER
-------------------- ---------- -----------
Miguel Martins               32           1
Miguel Martins               32           2
Another Person               19           3
Another Person               19           4
```

[SQL Fiddle doesn't like that](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f759/15), but [db<>fiddle does](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ef6b356cf9707ab022021301c3e31b8), and it works locally against 11gR2. (Actually [SQL Fiddle is OK with a real table instead of a CTE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcf1b9/1)...)

or

```
select t1.name, t1.age, t2.some_number
from my_with_clause
cross join xmltable (
  '/root/person'
  passing xmltype(my_with_clause.my_xml)
  columns name varchar2(20) path 'name',
    age number path 'age',
    list_of_numbers xmltype path 'list_of_numbers'
) t1
cross join xmltable (
  '/list_of_numbers/number'
  passing t1.list_of_numbers
  columns some_number number path '.'
) t2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da2332613e683362564b3be4947dc1b3)

With this XML you could also do it with one XMLTable by starting from the numbers and then looking back up the nodes for the other data:

```
select t1.name, t1.age, t1.some_number
from my_with_clause
cross join xmltable (
  '/root/person/list_of_numbers/number'
  passing xmltype(my_with_clause.my_xml)
  columns name varchar2(20) path './../../name',
    age number path './../../age',
    some_number number path '.'
) t1;

NAME                        AGE SOME_NUMBER
-------------------- ---------- -----------
Miguel Martins               32           1
Miguel Martins               32           2
Another Person               19           3
Another Person               19           4
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f759/16) and [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb8cf0ec7dfda4e8b9267ddc0efe8ce6).

but your real (not-minimal) XML might not make that practical.

---

This works with tables with multiple rows too, not just a CTE or table with a single XML value to unpack.

If you can have a scenario where the `list_of_names` is missing or empty, and you still want to show the name/age, you can use an outer join instead of a cross join, but it needs an ugly `on 1=1` clause. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4cfcd/2) showing the cross join and left join for that kind of data, but I'd avoid that left-join approach if you can.

If you're on 12c or higher you can use `outer apply` instead of `left join ... on 1=1`, which is rather less offensive. (And if you don't have to worry about missing numbers, you can use `cross apply` instead of `cross join` as @Lukasz showed - doesn't seem to make a difference here.)

---

The ORA-19025 is interesting. SQL Fiddle is running Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0. In Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4 your code gets

> ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

instead, but it's the same issue; there are multiple `number` nodes under each person, and it doesn't know what to do with them, as the default data type - since you haven't specified datatypes everything is returned as strings. In my first version I'm using the same path but declaring that column as XMLType, so you get the numbers as an XML fragment like this in the first version:

```
<number>1</number><number>2</number>
```

or this in the second:

```
<list_of_numbers><number>1</number><number>2</number></list_of_numbers>
```

Those can then be consumed by the chained XMLTable call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will perhaps go with the first approach of chaining the XMLTable calls. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one row, you could easily "chain" XMLTABLE with `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
select t.id, t1.Name, t1.Age, t2."number"
from t
CROSS APPLY xmltable('/root/person' passing xmltype(t.my_xml) 
                     columns name path 'name', age path 'age', 
                     list_of_numbers xmltype path 'list_of_numbers/number') t1
CROSS APPLY xmltable('/number' passing t1.list_of_numbers 
                     columns  "number" number path '.') t2
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c5fd4fe3bf901198462fa31bfa81a928)**

Main table is t, t1 refers using xmltype(t.my_xml) , and t2 refers parsed XML using t1.list_of_numbers.

---

**Addendum**:

**CROSS APPLY** and **CROSS JOIN** are equivalent when all XMLTABLE yield rows:

```
declare
  x VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
 dbms_utility.expand_sql_text(
        input_sql_text => q'{
          select t.id, t1.Name, t1.Age, t2."number"
from t
CROSS JOIN xmltable('/root/person' passing xmltype(t.my_xml) columns name path 'name', age path 'age', list_of_numbers xmltype path 'list_of_numbers/number') t1
CROSS JOIN xmltable('/number' passing t1.list_of_numbers columns  "number" number path '.') t2
}',
        output_sql_text => x);

  dbms_output.put_line(x);
end;
/

declare
  x VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
 dbms_utility.expand_sql_text(
        input_sql_text => q'{
          select t.id, t1.Name, t1.Age, t2."number"
from t
CROSS APPLY xmltable('/root/person' passing xmltype(t.my_xml) columns name path 'name', age path 'age', list_of_numbers xmltype path 'list_of_numbers/number') t1
CROSS APPLY xmltable('/number' passing t1.list_of_numbers columns  "number" number path '.') t2
}',
        output_sql_text => x);

  dbms_output.put_line(x);
end;
/
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=52b0010860a1d4c5b6fdaeca94ccd058)**

---

The difference is visible when we have XML like:

```
<root>
  <person>
    <name>XXXX</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </person>
</root>

select t.id, t1.Name, t1.Age, t2."number"
from t
OUTER APPLY xmltable('/root/person' passing xmltype(t.my_xml) columns name path 'name', age path 'age', list_of_numbers xmltype path 'list_of_numbers/number') t1
OUTER APPLY xmltable('/number' passing t1.list_of_numbers columns  "number" number path '.') t2
```

CROSS JOIN  - 0 rows

OUTER APPLY - 1 row

Comment: What's the advantage here of cross apply vs cross join? They both work with multiple rows from a table - not sure when they would give different results? (I get outer apply allowing for missing number list...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Hmmm, you are right and it seems they are equivalent in that case. The outer apply is simple(when XML yield no result) **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4fa77b9c83408f931f6c866893d45550)**

Comment: @AlexPoole It turned out that both CROSS JOIN/CROSS APPLY use `LATERAL` join so they are the same.  LATERAL and CROSS APPLY are synonyms so it was obvious for me, that I was a bit surprised it worked with CROSS JOIN too.

Comment: Yes, I usually use cross join, I might reconsider and use cross apply, at least for answers that aren't for 11g. I wasn't sure if I was missing something; seems not, but apply seems more natural now I think about it. (Maybe cross join works like that here *because* 11g didn't have apply?) I put a small section in my answer about using an outer join but it's ugly so didn't include that code and advised against; and referred to your answer for cross/outer apply. Thanks.